# Tab transitions within Modal (Ionic)

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, modal-dialog

I need to open a modal, which displays a page that uses a `tab` style of transitioning between pages.

I cannot browse between links within the modal (without closing the modal). I want to create a tab-like transition between tabs in the modal.

For links which close the modal, I use the `closeModal()`. It works on my browser but on devices, it must use Ionic's native a `href` behaviour which over-rides closeModal():

```
<a href="#/storeshop/{{stores[i].id}}" ng-click="closeModal()">
```

Here

```
$ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('app/components/stores/stores.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
}).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
});

$scope.refineevent = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
};

$scope.closeModal = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
};    

$scope.$on('modal.shown', function() {
    console.log('Modal is shown!');
});
```

My HTML:

```
<ion-modal-view>
<ion-view name="stores"><ion-pane ng-controller="storesCtrl">

        <ion-content class="has-header">
  ...
        </ion-content>
    <div class="faketab">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="stores">STORE DIRECTORY</a></td>
            <td><a href="stylsts">STYLIST</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

</ion-view>
</ion-modal-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [$state](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Quick-Reference#stategoto--toparams--options) to transition to the new state.

```
<a ng-click="goToStore(stores[i].id)">



    $scope.goToStore= function(storeId) 
    {
       $scope.modal.hide();
       $state.go('tab.storeshop',{id:}
    };
```